# zebra stripes css for dynamical list item

Tags: jquery, css

I can't change my html because this is the hack for me to do something (sorting algo), however it broke my css because I can't use even and odd anymore..

http://jsfiddle.net/Hms7Y/24/

try to add 1 and then follow by 2, it has the same background.. I tried to apply 3 classes for 3 li, doesn't work because there are various behaviour by users.

```
li:nth-child(even){
background:#DDD;    
}
```

Comment: So, the solution you came up with is causing a problem, but we can't change the 'solution' you've chosen, and instead have to solve the problem introduced by the 'solution'? I think you might want to re-think your approach, because clearly your solution isn't working out, and that should be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, it is working - but since you've hidden every second item, the (uncoloured) items aren't visible. The _apparent_ result - items aren't coloured. As David said - you need to either (a) change the 'hack' as you put it that (I pressume) is hiding the even elements or (b) change the way that you colour alternate items in the unordered-list.

Comment: @enhzflep is it possible to use js?

Comment: If I removed the hidden li, it'll be hard for me to perform my sorting algo, this is the simplest hack I found..

Comment: Gave it some thought, you are trying to create a Zebra pattern and want to insert elements **between** the pattern and you hope that rest of the CSS will take care of itself? Think how much this 'hack' is costing you. There is always another way.

Comment: @GauravBhor you should stay and watch us do it!

Comment: @RickiVandenbroek - yup, sure is. Just use JS to set the class attribute. I.e for every second _displayed_ item, set the .className attribute. E.g, use a css class of `.even { background:#DDD; };` and then add the `even` class.  `liElement.className += ' even';` The space before even intentional - you need to take class="level" and turn it into class="level even" - so, you add a space and then the class name. I also note, that if you press 1 over and over again it does still work. Also, you're generating this as html (it's not valid) `<li class="level" 1="">1</li>` You should fix that (first).

Comment: I'm not going anywhere. Good luck!

Comment: @GauravBhor http://jsfiddle.net/kidino/JRwM7/1/ impossible is nothing

Comment: You did it. Great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kidino/JRwM7/1/

just use :visible to filter the hidden li in js

```
  $('ul li').removeClass('even');
  $('ul li:visible:odd').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNsVB/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var lvl = $('select').val();

    $('<li class="level" '+ lvl + '>' + lvl + '</li>').appendTo('ul');
  });
});
```

Comment: it work for styling, but 1 can be below of 2, which is not I want